# Non-gradual color change in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, glsl, glfw, opengl-4

I'm trying to gradually change a triangle's color to each color on the spectrum. The color basically changes incrementally in every iteration of the render loop and passes the color information to a uniform variable. The problem is that it's lagging between multiple iterations and not changing gradually. The rgb values on the main program are changing gradually, but the color of the triangle in the end is not. I've had no problem performing this (gradually changing colors) on the whole window without a triangle however.

Here's the code of the triangle spectrum program and a preview of its output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include "include/glad/glad.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

void framebufferSizeCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height){
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

void processInput(GLFWwindow* window){
    ;
}

char * parseFile(const char * fileName){
    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (!fp) perror(fileName),exit(1);

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END); // go to the end
    long lsize = ftell(fp);  // size is how far it is from the start
    rewind(fp);              // reset to the start to prepare for reading

    char *buffer = calloc(1, lsize+1); //assign (lsize) blocks of memory to buffer
    if (!buffer) fclose(fp),fputs("Failed to allocate memory.",stderr),exit(1);

    if(1!=fread(buffer,lsize,1,fp))
        fclose(fp),free(buffer),fputs("Failed to read file.", stderr),exit(1);
    
    fclose(fp);

    return buffer;
}

int main(void){
    glfwInit();

    if (glfwInit() != GLFW_TRUE){
        printf("Failed to initialize GLFW.");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MINOR, 6);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_ANY_PROFILE);

    int windowSize = 600;
    
    GLFWwindow* window;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(windowSize, windowSize, "spectrum", NULL, NULL);
    
    if (window == NULL){
        printf("Failed to create window.\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)){
        printf("Failed to initialize GLAD.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, windowSize, windowSize);

    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebufferSizeCallback);

    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    const char *vertexShader = parseFile("timeTriangleShaders/vert.glsl");
    const char *fragmentShader = parseFile("timeTriangleShaders/frag.glsl");

    unsigned int vertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShaderID, 1, &vertexShader, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShaderID);

    unsigned int fragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShaderID, 1, &fragmentShader, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShaderID);

    unsigned int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShaderID);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    free((char*)vertexShader);
    free((char*)fragmentShader);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderID);
    
    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    float vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
         0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f
    };

    unsigned int VAO, VBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3*sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 1); // unbind VBO
    glBindVertexArray(0);             // unbind VAO

    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    float min = 0;
    float max = 255;
    float rgb[] = {min, max, min}; // g,r,b instead of r,g,b to emulate spectrum
    int pos = 0;
    int increment = 10;

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        int colorUniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "color");

        if ((rgb[pos] >= max && increment > 0) || (rgb[pos] <= min && increment < 0)){
            rgb[pos] = rgb[pos] > max ? max : min;
            pos = pos == 2 ? 0 : ++pos;
            increment = -increment;
        }
        else rgb[pos] += increment;

        printf("rgb: (%3.f, %3.f, %3.f) | %3d\n", rgb[1], rgb[0], rgb[2], increment);

        glUniform4f(colorUniformLocation, rgb[1], rgb[0], rgb[2], 1.0f);

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Fragment Shader of the spectrum triangle program:

```
#version 460 core
out vec4 FragColor;
uniform vec4 color;

void main(){
    FragColor = color;
}
```

Vertex Shader of the spectrum triangle program:

```
#version 460 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

void main(){
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

Output of spectrum triangle program:
[spectrum triangle program NOT changing colors gradually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ6h2.gif)

The code of the simple spectrum program with glClearColor:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// #define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include "include/glad/glad.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

void framebufferSizeCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height){
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

int main(void){
    glfwInit();

    if (glfwInit() != GLFW_TRUE){
        printf("Failed to initialize GLFW.");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MINOR, 6);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_ANY_PROFILE);

    int windowSize = 600;
    
    GLFWwindow* window;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(windowSize, windowSize, "spectrum", NULL, NULL);
    
    if (window == NULL){
        printf("Failed to create window.\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)){
        printf("Failed to initialize GLAD.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, windowSize, windowSize);

    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebufferSizeCallback);

    float min = 0;
    float max = 255;
    float rgb[] = {min, max, min}; // g,r,b instead of r,g,b to emulate spectrum
    int pos = 0;
    int increment = 10;

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
        glClearColor(rgb[1]/255, rgb[0]/255, rgb[2]/255, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        if ((rgb[pos] >= max && increment > 0) || (rgb[pos] <= min && increment < 0)){
            rgb[pos] = rgb[pos] > max ? max : min;
            pos = pos == 2 ? 0 : ++pos;
            increment = -increment;
        }
        else rgb[pos] += increment;

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Output of simple spectrum program with GlClearColor:
[spectrum program with glClearColor gradually changing colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLQxq.gif)

I've tried changing the point of the logic where the color gets incremented but to no avail. Using vec3 instead of vec4 then adjusting the fragment shader also didn't help. Replicating [LearnOpenGL's code](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Shaders) which changes from green to nothing gradually work's flawlessly however.

[LearnOpenGL Triangle changing from green to nothing gradually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXuEc.gif)

Comment: Look at what you're passing to `glClearColor` and compare to what you're passing to `glUniform4f`.

Comment: Note that even if you fix that, nothing in here guarantees that the colour change is smooth, that'd require actually checking how much time is passing between each iteration and making your change depend on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The channels of the fragment shader color output should be in the [0.0, 1.0] range, not [0.0, 255.0].

Divide `rgb[]` by 255 host-side like you're doing in the `glClearColor()` example before passing the values to `glUniform4f()`:

```cpp
glUniform4f(colorUniformLocation, rgb[1]/255, rgb[0]/255, rgb[2]/255, 1.0f);
```